# Why expected value is optimal?

Tags: optimization, soft-question

The expected value is widely used and considered optimal. The question is why it is optimal. The Wikipedia page or other google search on the topic does not clearly state why and under what condition the expected value is optimal. Any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing is "optimal" in an absolute sense. Something is or is not optimal according to a defined, precise criterion.

Say you have a real random variable $X$. You want to find a number $m$ that minimizes $\text{E}[(X-m)^2]$. It turns out that $m = \text{E}[X]$. In this sense, the expected value is "optimal".

Under a different set of criteria, the mean is no longer optimal.

Comment: "Under a different set of criteria, the mean is no longer optimal."  Indeed. As you undoubtedly know, if the criterion is minimum $E[|X-m|]$ which minimizes the mean _absolute_ error instead of the mean _square_ error, then $m$ should  be chosen as the _median_ of $X$, the point where the CDF $F_X(\cdot)$ has value $\frac 12$.

Comment: Indeed - good example!.